# Sql query to get total records for specific table available in multiple databases on same server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one requirement where I need to find the total number of records in specific table "ENTITY", available in all the databases that we have on our SQL Server. I want to write a single query to get records from multiple databases for this table. Can someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Single table, multiple databases?

Comment: hint: create procedure

Comment: @GordonLinoff- Yes, our application is being used by different companies but all those companies must use the same database design. So, any table which is available at one client db would be there for another one too.

Answer (score 0):

**Option One**

```
SELECT  SUM(P.[Rows]) AS [Count]
FROM    SYS.objects O
JOIN    SYS.partitions P
ON      P.[object_id] = O.[object_id]
AND     P.index_id < 2
WHERE   O.name = 'Table'
```

**Option Two**

```
SELECT  COUNT(1)
FROM    dbo.Table
```

Comment: You could apply either of these to multiple databases (even in the same query) using linked server connections.